# numpy.random has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, numpy, enthought

I am using python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-1 (64-bit) and for some reason numpy.random.choice is not working:

from the terminal window:

```
d-108-179-168-72:~ home$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.1-1 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  3 2011, 15:56:02) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "packages", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.choice(5, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

any ideas of what the problem could be?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it could be the version of numpy your distribution is using. From [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) choice was only added in 1.7.0 and from [the enthought package](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/package-index/) I can see it only has 1.6.1 in version 7.2, a later version than your own. You may wish to upgrade your version of numpy.

Comment: I think you are right, that was the problem. I upgraded to Canopy and my numpy version is now 1.9.2 and it works.
Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does it have `randint`?

```
np.random.randint(0,5,3)
```

should do the same thing